# Changing default video player in Google Chrome for Android

Tags: chrome-for-android, video-streaming, airplay

***tl;dr***

When you open any video, default HTML5 player is used.

What I want is to make Google Chrome to use custom video player whenever it wants to playback a video

***Longer story***
My real goal is to stream video content from Android to AppleTV via AirPlay. I found a nice app called *streambels* which is capable of doing that.

The only problem is when I am trying to watch video on Google Chrome, I can't stream it so if I could change the default video player would allow me to pass the video to broadcasting app. And life would be so great :)

Answer (score -1):

Use [Dolphin Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser).  I think what you are asking is impossible for now on Chrome.

Comment: Have you used this app and made certain that this will solve OP's question? If not, then please post a brief description of this app to show why OP should use it for the relevant purpose.

Answer (score -1):

I use the [BUBBLEUPNP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bubblesoft.android.bubbleupnp) application.

Once I click on the link, Chrome asks me what to do; Chrome or upnp app. I choose the upnp app. Once the UpnpApp is open it asks me what video player to use.